# Array of objects, removing duplicates but storing values (i.e. grouping)

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I am currently working on a list of customers returns from my database.

The customers are saved as objects that are build from two joined tables.
The joined table returns duplicates since there are no array like structure in my First Normal form database.

So consider an array like this

```
var customers = [
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Cars'}, 
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Computers'},
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Babes'},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Food'}, 
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Toys'},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Cake'}];
```

I've been trying like mad but i can only find examples for removing duplicates in simple arrays, with no object `[1,2,3]` etc.

Ultimately what i want to do is remove duplicates but to save the interest.
A list of object like this, given the sample array from above.

```
var reduced =[
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe' interests : ['Cars', 'Computers', 'Babes']},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith' interests : ['Food', 'Toys', 'Cake']}];
```

I have tried removing duplicates like this so far

```
for(var i = 0; i < newCustomersArray.length; i++){
        console.log(i)
        if(i == 0){
            console.log('i = 0, customerId ' + newCustomersArray[i].firstname)
            data.customers.push(newCustomersArray[i]);
        }
        //else if(newCustomersArray[i-1].customerId != newCustomersArray[i].customerId){
        //    
        //}
        else if( newCustomersArray[i-1].customerId != newCustomersArray[i].customerId){
            //console.log(newCustomersArray[i-1].customerId + " == " + newCustomersArray[i].customerId);
            console.log('i = '+i+', customerId ' + newCustomersArray[i].firstname)
            data.customers.push(newCustomersArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you try group by in database query so that duplicates can avoid there itself?

Comment: Yep, a simple grouping can solve your problem on server side. Doing it yourself, especially in javascript, will be clumsy and expansive

Comment: Sorry, should have added some context,
I have tried removing duplicates so far, ill add the code bit in the question.
Saving the interests in the list however is a problem i cant wrap my head around so far,

Comment: Will it always be in order by id?

Comment: Yes it will, the result is ordered by Id from server side.

Comment: Also, will the id always be one more than the previous one, or may there be some missing ids?

Comment: Id is only 1,2 in the example for simplification

Comment: Do it on the server side. GROUP BY and [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySql will be a good starting point.

Comment: @Jan GROUP CONCAT has the disadvantage of turning multiple separate values into one value, which means a) you still have to process (split) it on the client side and b) You get into escaping troubles if your data contains the separator char.

Comment: @Tomalak Right you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some of the Array methods to build your new array, like [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var customers = [
        { id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe', interest: 'Cars' },
        { id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe', interest: 'Computers' },
        { id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe', interest: 'Babes' },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Frank', lastname: 'Smith', interest: 'Food' },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Frank', lastname: 'Smith', interest: 'Toys' },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Frank', lastname: 'Smith', interest: 'Cake' }
    ], reduced = [];

customers.forEach(function (a) {
    !reduced.some(function (b) {
        if (a.id === b.id) {
            b.interests.push(a.interest);
            return true;
        }
    }) && reduced.push({ id: a.id, firstname: a.firstname, lastname: a.lastname, interests: [a.interest] });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(reduced, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution, and great with some explenation.
Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Use array.reduce method on customers object to eliminate duplicates.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Please refer sample below code

```js
var customers = [
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Cars'}, 
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Computers'},
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Babes'},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Food'}, 
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Toys'},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Cake'}];

var temp = customers.reduce(function(o,n){
o = o || {};
if(!o[n.firstname+n.lastname+n.id]){
o[n.firstname+n.lastname+n.id] = n;
o[n.firstname+n.lastname+n.id].interest = []
}
o[n.firstname+n.lastname+n.id].interest.push(n.interest);
return o;
},{});

customers = Object.keys(temp).map(function(k) { return temp[k] })

console.log(customers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an objects (that have unique keys) to eliminate duplicates:

```
var tempObj = {};
for(i=0; i<customers.length;i++){
    if(tempObj[customers[i].id] == undefined){
        tempObj[customers[i].id] = customers[i];
    }
    else{
        tempObj[customers[i].id].interest = tempObj[customers[i].id].interest + ","+customers[i].interest;
    }
}
```

here a demo https://jsfiddle.net/h2aeeth6/

Answer (score 1):

You can write just simple logic,

```
var customers = [
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Cars'}, 
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Computers'},
{id : 1, firstname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe', interest : 'Babes'},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Food'}, 
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Toys'},
{id : 2, firstname : 'Frank', lastname : 'Smith', interest : 'Cake'}];

        for (var i=0;i<customers.length;i++){
            var intrest=[customers[i].interest];
            for (var j=i+1; j<customers.length; j++)
            {
                if (customers[i].id == customers[j].id){
                    intrest.push(customers[j].interest);
                    customers.splice(j,1);
                    j--;
                 }
              }
                customers[i].interest=intrest;
       }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(customers));
```